# Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume generated by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the y-axis.

Tags: calculus, integration

Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume generated by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the $y$-axis.

$$y = e^{-x^2},\ y = 0,\ x = 0,\ x = 1$$

How the fudge am I supposed to do this without parts? Is there supposed to be some kind of antiderivative to this function with an $x$ in front of it or something? This is like three functions in one.

Obviously I can get as far as $2\pi\displaystyle\int_0^1xe^{-x^2}dx$ but yeah...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you may have reached the right integral, which is
$$\int_0^1 2\pi xe^{-x^2}\, dx.$$
You can quickly integrate by making the substitution $u=x^2$.

Comment: i've been taking too long of a break in homework... thanks

Comment: You are welcome. The term $e^{-x^2}$ is admittedly scary. There is no elementary function whose derivative is $e^{-x^2}$. But the $2x$ in front was *very* helpful.